# Wicket : Add a list to a datatable

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-7

I have a list of object to display in a table with wicket.
Those object are composed of a String and an Array of String.

My problem is that i don't know how to add this array into my table. And second, i have some css that I need to apply to each of my String of the array, so each of them have to be on a different div/span/li.

Can it be a good idea to concatenate all those elements and add the "div" manually ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You need to decide what kind of HTML you want to produce for these objects. And then we can advise you how to do it.

Comment: I don't really have any obligation/preferences, as long as I can put them some information to apply some CSS (id/class). I was looking if i could maybe put a list in a list, but without any good result...

Comment: There are thousand ways to represent the array of strings: you can join the elements with comma, e.g. abc,def,...", or you can render `<ul><li>abc</li><li>def</li/...</ul>`, or even an inner table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been to obssesed with using a datatable. By using a list in a list it work just fine !

JAVA :

```
ListView<Profil> listProfil = new ListView<Profil>("listProfils", profils) {
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<Profil> item) {
        Profil tmpProfil = item.getModelObject();
        item.add(new Label("libelle", tmpProfil.getLibelle()));
        item.add( new ListView("listChamps", tmpProfil.getChamps()) {
            protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
                item.add(new Label("libelleChamps", item.getModel()));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And the associate HTML template :

```
<tr wicket:id="listProfils">
    <div class="row">
        <td class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text">
            <span wicket:id="libelle"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="col-xs-7 col-md-8 col-lg-8 text" colspan="3">
            <span wicket:id="listChamps">
                <span wicket:id="libelleChamps" 
                class="label label-default badge badge-tag" >Champs</span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </div>
</tr >
```

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice in Wicket, to build a Table in HTML that is being fed from a List, you need the following elements:

#### HTML

```
<table wicket:id="yourWicketIdOfDataTableObject">[table]
</table>
```

#### JAVA

A POJO (`pojoObject`) that represents each element (`o regiser`) of your table

A DataProvider (`dataProviderObject`) class that extends from `SortableDataProvider<pojoObject, String>`

You need to override the `iterator()`, `size()` and `model()` methods according to your needs.

A `List<IColumn<pojoObject,String>> columnsObject`

The above object will represent the colums of your table.

You could add columns as follows:

`columnsObject.add(new PropertyColumn<pojoObject,String>(new Model<String>("nameOfTheColum"),pojoObjectPropertyName))`

A DefaultDataTable `tableObject`:

`DataTable<pojoObject, String> = new DefaultDataTable("yourWicketIdOfDataTableObject", columnsObject, dataProviderObject, NumOfColumns)`

The above object will represent the table.

As you might see `pojoObject` wraped by `columnsObject` and `dataProviderObject`, and these two will be wrapped by `tableObject` at the end. Your array will be accessed in the `iterator()` method of the `dataProviderObject`, because it needs to retrieve the iterator of the list; The `pojoObject` that represent the each element of your actual list will be necessary (in case you don't have one yet)

At the end, you only need add `tableObject` in their Wicket Parent, as any other Wicket Component.